# Openerp Functional Field

Tags: python

Can anyone please explain this code in brief? I am new to python programming.

```
_name = 'sale.order.line'
_description = 'Sales Order Line'
_columns = {
'invoiced': fields.function(_fnct_line_invoiced, string='Invoiced', type='boolean',
        store={
          'account.invoice': (_order_lines_from_invoice, ['state'], 10),
          'sale.order.line': (lambda self,cr,uid,ids,ctx=None: ids, ['invoice_lines'], 10)}),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is the definition of a special kind of functional field.

By definition, an openerp functional field is not the typical model field that you will store in the database, but the results from calculations made over other fields in the model.

This time the presence of "store" attribute in the functional field definition will modifies that rule, by instruct the openerp engine to actually grab this field in the database.

While

'account.invoice': (_order_lines_from_invoice, ['state'], 10),

indicates the "_order_lines_from_invoice" function will be called for any changes on field 'state' in the 'account.invoice' object, with priority ten.

Seriously, explained so much better here: https://doc.odoo.com/6.1/developer/03_modules_2/#functional-fields

and yes! even better: http://members.hellug.gr/xrg/openerp-doc/html/api_reference/osv/fields_function.html#field-function-store

Comment: Thank you for Your reply. It's helped me a lot. Can you please explain how to run a function automatically when a field in another object changes...??Thanks in advance..

Comment: May be you need to use the "on_change" attribute for do so.

Take a look here http://members.hellug.gr/xrg/openerp-doc/html/search.html?sections=developer&q= 

Off course, you may want to put "on_change" in the "Query:" text entry box.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..I have a custom module in openerp 7.0 that create customer invoices in account.invoice model.All is working fine.But now i want to display status 'Done' in the same custom module when invoice get paid..Its very urgent please help me with a sample code and its explanation---user3801825